# Why does this code create an infinite loop?when Instantiate a gameobject and set it parent

Tags: unity-game-engine

Why does this code create an infinite loop? Does it represent one loop when it instantiates a GameObject and then sets its parent?

```
    public GameObject ui;
    GameObject child;
    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            child = Instantiate(ui);
            child.transform.SetParent(ui.transform,false);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiation makes a copy of an object with all of its hierarchy. You're making copy of `ui` and assigning it as a child of the original `ui` object, so your hierarchy now looks like this:

```
ui (original)
-ui (copy)
```

In the next iteration of loop `ui` object is getting cloned again and becomes this:

```
ui
-ui
-ui (copy of ui with new child)
--ui
```

On the third iteration it will be doubled again. See where it is going?

---

And finally, I assume that your script that copies the `ui` is... on that `ui` object, thus is also copied each time, leading to the endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding `child` to `ui` in the loop. Then in next iteration the `ui` GameObject you instantiated has been changed by previous iteration.